# How to select a specific checklistbox item by it's value in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, checklistbox

I have a checkListBox that has 3 items using DisplayMembers and ValueMembers.  The DisplayMember and ValueMember are populated from a database table.

Here is sample data, ID being ValueMember and Name being DisplayMember.

```
ID | Name
---------
1    john
2    tim
```

I want to programatically select a specific item in that checkListBox, for example check the checkbox for  "tim", but by the ValueMember, so if the ValueMember of the item equals 2, then check the checkbox.

Here's my code so far:

```
foreach (DataRowView view in clb.Items)
{
  if (view.Row[0].ToString() == 2)
  {
    **code to checkbox goes here**
  }
}
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to check the item it's on.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the item you can use:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked).checked = true;
```

If not you can use the **number** of the item in the first column and use it in the second one.